# Refer to javascript function from within itself

Tags: javascript

Consider this piece of code

```
var crazy = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.isCrazy); // wrong.
}
crazy.isCrazy = 'totally';
crazy();
// ouput =>
// DOMWindow
// undefined
```

From inside crazy() 'this' refers to the window, which I guess makes sense because normally  you'd want this to refer to the object the function is attached to, but how can I get the function to refer to itself, and access a property set on itself?

**Answer:**

Don't use arguments.callee, just use a named function.

"Note: You should avoid using arguments.callee() and just give every function (expression) a name." via [MDN article on arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you are asking for arguments.callee, but it's **deprecated** now.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee

```
var crazy = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(arguments.callee.isCrazy); // right.
}
crazy.isCrazy = 'totally';
crazy();
// ouput =>
// DOMWindow
// totally
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. How to refer to the function, from within that function, regardless of whether it is attached to an object or not, of if it has a name declared within the parent closure. Now i think about it, I already knew this, but never thought of it outside of removing anonymous event listener functions.

Comment: If the second line of the function is not in fact wrong, do you mind removing the //wrong. from it? It makes the initial read confusing.

Comment: Danger! Not a best practice! Will fail in 'use strict' mode. There are other ways of solving this issue out there.

Comment: You're right D: - `Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`

Comment: @MattJensen such as?

Comment: @geoidesic "Avoid using arguments.callee() by either giving function expressions a name or use a function declaration where a function must call itself." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Answer (score 18):

As **rfw** said, this is the most straight forward way to go if the function has one single name:

```
var crazy = function() {
    console.log(crazy);
    console.log(crazy.isCrazy);
};

crazy.isCrazy = 'totally';
crazy();
```

In case it may have different names, or you wanted to pass it around, it must be wrapped in a closure:

```
var crazy = (function(){
    var that = function() {
        console.log(that);
        console.log(that.isCrazy);
    };
    return that;
})();

crazy.isCrazy = 'totally';
crazy();
```

Comment: Good thinking on the closure.

Comment: by the way, the arguments array is only populated if needed, so one should avoid using it if speed matters (as far as I remember, please confirm)

Comment: this is also called trampolining

Answer (score 11):

Bind the function to itself (taking a hint from answers by @ArunPJohny and @BudgieInWA):

```
crazy = crazy.bind(crazy);
```

This will give you access from the function to its properties via `this`.

```
> crazy()
function () {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.isCrazy); // works now
}
```

This seems like a better solution than the accepted answer, which uses the `callee` feature which is deprecated and doesn't work in strict mode.

You could also now have the function call itself recursively with `this()` were you so inclined.

We will call this **self-thisifying**. Write a little utility function:

```
function selfthisify(fn) { return fn.bind(fn); }
crazy = selfthisify(crazy);
crazy();
```

Or, if you prefer more "semantic" names, you could call it `accessOwnProps`.

If you're a syntactic sugar type of person, you could add a `selfthisify` property to the Function prototype:

```
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'selfthisify', {
    get: function() { return this.bind(this); }
});
```

Now you can say

```
crazy.selfthisify();
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to give it its own name, so:

```
var crazy = function() {
    console.log(crazy);
    console.log(crazy.isCrazy);
}
crazy.isCrazy = 'totally';
crazy();
```

The variable `this` is only applicable in the scope of an object, for instance, if you invoked your version of the `crazy` function with `crazy.call(crazy)`, it will call the function in the context of the function `crazy` and all would be well.

Answer (score 3):

This has to deal with the scope of the function `crazy`. If can pass any scope to a function using the function `call()`.

Instead of

```
crazy();
```

Use

```
crazy.call(crazy);
```

For details refer
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call
http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `call` method

```
var crazy = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.isCrazy);
}
crazy.isCrazy = 'totally';
crazy.call(crazy);
// calls crazy using crazy as the target, instead of window:
// functionToCall.call(objectToUseForThis);
```

Though if your function only ever has one name, you can do this:

```
var crazy = function() {
    console.log(crazy);
    console.log(crazy.isCrazy);
}
crazy.isCrazy = 'totally';
crazy();
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. 'this' becomes attached to whatever object you call() the function on. Sweet.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to make the function itself available in its body is to do
`var crazy = function crazy2() { crazy2(); }`, it's okay for crazy and crazy2 to have the same name since the first occurrence is the name in the outer scope and the second is the name in the function body.

Or simply do `function crazy() { crazy(); }` which will define crazy in both scopes.

Comment: I didn't know functions assigned to var could still be named, very nice! +1

Answer (score 1):

> how can I get the function to refer to
>   itself?

The idea of 'itself' does not exist with functions. What you need is an object and not just a function. An object has knowledge of itself available through the keyword 'this'. Within a function, 'this' points to the global object - in this case the window object. But if you use your function as a constructor function to create an object (using the *new* operator) then the object's 'this' pointer will point to the object itself.

i.e *this* points to the object if you write:

```
var anObject = new crazy();
```

So you can re-write your code as follows:

```
var crazy = function() {
    this.printMe = function(){
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.isCrazy); 
    }
}

var anObject = new crazy(); //create an object
anObject.isCrazy = 'totally'; //add a new property to the object
anObject.printMe(); //now print
```

In case you wish to add the property *before* the object is created, then you have to add the property to the function's *prototype* as follows:

```
var crazy = function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.isCrazy); 
}

crazy.prototype.isCrazy = 'totally'; //add the property to the function's prototype
var anObject = new crazy(); //invoke the constructor
```

See more on [my blog](http://rahuldotout.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/professional-javascript-part-6-objects-without-classes/) for a detailed explanation of these concepts with code-samples.

Comment: StackOverflow exists to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers. When your short url service dies, or your blog article gets moved around, or your blogging service dies, this answer becomes even more useless. Please at the very least include copy-and-paste snippets of the portions of your article that directly address the question. SO doesn't exist to just be another boring link exchange site. Thanks!

Comment: @sarnold: Thanks for pointing it out. I fully agree with you on this. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I find this answer quite misleading. First off, functions are first class objects in JS and as such there definitely __is__ an idea of itself for a function. Secondly, `this` does not refer to an object's self in JS but rather to the context in which a function is called. The very same function can have different `this` each time it is called depending on how it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually trying to create an object 'class'?

```
function crazy(crazyState) {
   this.isCrazy = crazyState;
   console.log(this);
   console.log(this.isCrazy);
}
crazy.prototype.alertMe = function() { alert('I am '+ this.isCrazy +' crazy.'); }

var crazyObj = new crazy('totally');
crazyObj.alertMe();

crazyObj.isCrazy = 'not';
crazyObj.alertMe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny that you should ask, mate.  I just went through [this same issue for a different purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084872/an-object-that-returns-an-instance-of-itself). The quick version of the final code is:

```
$a = function() {};

$ = function() {
    if (!(this instanceof $)) {
        return new $();
    }

    this.name = "levi";

    return this;
};

//helper function
var log = function(message) {
    document.write((message ? message : '') + "<br/>");
};

log("$().name == window.name: " + ($().name == window.name)); //false
log("$().name: " + $().name); //levi
log("window.name: " + window.name); //result

log();

log("$a instanceof $: " + ($a instanceof $)); //false
log("typeof $a: " + (typeof $a)); //function
log("typeof $: " + (typeof $)); //function
```

The critical piece:

```
    if (!(this instanceof $)) {
        return new $();
    }
```

If `this` isn't pointing to an object of the right type, then it makes a `new` one, which will properly scope `this`.  The rest of the code is just there for verification that it does indeed work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

**In order to make you code to work follow below**

```js
        function crazy_object (crazy) {
          this.isCrazy = crazy
        }
        
        var create_crazy = new crazy_object('hello') //creating object
        
        console.log(create_crazy); //=> { isCrazy = 'hello' }
        
        var crazy = function() {
            console.log(this); //=> { isCrazy = 'totally' }
            console.log(this.isCrazy); //=> 'totally'
        }
        
        create_crazy.isCrazy = 'totally'; //=> isCrazy = 'totally'
        //below we pass the created object in function crazy.
        //And doing that we can use the keywork `this` and refer to the object
        crazy.call(create_crazy, null);
```

> Using the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method we can pass to a function a
>   property,and in that function we can use the property with the keyword `this`

**For example:**

```js
function speak (message) {
  console.log(`A person with name ${this.name} say ${message}`);
}

speak.call({ name: 'Roland' }, 'Javascript is awesome');
```

To use it with property:

```
function speak (message) {
  console.log(`A person with name ${this.name} say ${message}`);
}

var name = 'Roland'

speak.call({ name }, 'Javascript is awesome');
```